# The created external list does not support creating new items

Tags: bcs

i have BCS with external list that read list and read item is from a table. 
and create new item  is from Stored Procedure.
i'm using applicative user who has full permissions (work directly from  SQLserver.)
however i succeeded to create the BCS but when i'm creating an External list it gives me "The created external list does not support creating new items".
the SP is with the same type and name as the read item.

p.s.
this  ECT is used also as association to another ECT.

Help will be appreciated,

Thanks,
Omri

Comment: Hi Omri, have you checked in the BCS service on Central Admin that you have the appropriate permissions for you entity?

Comment: hi,Thanks for the reply, i have another External list against other SP that work with the same BCS. and it works perfect. does i need to define it to different Tables?

Comment: Basically you'r saying that you have 2 external list using the same BCS and the same ECT but the first support creating new items and the second not?

Comment: no, i have two ECT one handles Table 1 through sp1 and the second handles Table 2 with sp2 both through the same BCS but different ECT.

Comment: Ok, It seems like the problem could be in the code that handles the Insert command, have you tried debugging?

Comment: i ran the SP in the DB with the Applicative user and it ran perfect. one more thing, i even try to insert directory among the Table (from the SPD) and it gave same result. doesn't support creating new items